# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate

when I add the code into my spring configuration file beans-hibernate.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

It doesn't work and I don't know why, can someone help me please ?

My Dao Class is :

```
public class CourseDaoImpl implements CourseDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void store(Course course) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(course);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(Long courseId) {
        Course course =  (Course)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Course.class, courseId);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(course);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Course findById(Long courseId) {
        return (Course)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Course.class,   courseId);
    }

        @Transactional
        public List<Course> findAll() {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Course");
        return (List<Course>)query.list();
    }

}
```

but :

```
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:18 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
Infos: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6ba8fb1b: startup date [Wed Jul 04 03:38:18 CEST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:18 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
Infos: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans-hibernate.xml]
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
Infos: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5a7fed46: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,sessionFactory,transactionManager,courseDao]; root of factory hierarchy
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.3.Final}
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring]
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=Bilal, password=****}
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: public.course
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [fee, id, title, end_date, begin_date]
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [course_pkey]
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
Infos: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5a7fed46: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,sessionFactory,transactionManager,courseDao]; root of factory hierarchy
juil. 04, 2012 3:38:19 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [beans-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.boutaya.bill.main.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:123)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.SessionFactoryImplementor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

I think the problem is when I use the Class : org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908452/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-engine-sessionfactoryimplementor

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forget to add

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

into your spring configuration xml file.

Actually, you need obviously define transaction-manager name only if it differs from standard (transactionManager). But in my example I left it.

Also with previous hibernate versions (4 and greater) used another transaction manager class:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is a issue of version conflict, you can not use hibernate 4:

> INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.3.Final}

with **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager**

try **org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager** instead

and if you want to enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations, add following to beans-hibernate.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```