# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor from Spring 3.1.2/Hibernate 4.1.7 and Shards 3.0.0.Beta2

Tags: spring, hibernate, exception, maven, sharding

I'm trying a simple Hibernate shard example (Yes, odd, 3.0.0.Beta2 released 4 years ago) using Hibernate Core 4.1.7 and Spring 3.1.2 and hit this issue during session factory initialization:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [shardedspring-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory it.sella.lab.crm.sys.persistence.ShardedSessionFactoryBuilder.createSessionFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at in.rixx.crm.model.Activity.<clinit>(Activity.java:17)
```

This is how I pick Spring and Hibernate:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

This doesn't seem like a issue with shards library - it looks like a general issue caused by refactored SessionFactoryImplementor class. Referring to https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8885, I've also switched to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager for bean 'transactionmanager' - it isn't helping.

Is there any functional workaround right now for Spring 3.x and Hibernate 4.x?

Comment: try the answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908452/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-engine-sessionfactoryimplementor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using HIbernate 4 with spring. So seems like spring & hibernate inter-compatibiity issue. So please visit below site for Hibernate 4 compatibility with spring.

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/

Else as another option try below version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

> I too faced the same issue i searched some other sites and its helped
>   me to resolve this issue.What i done wrong is hibernate version i used
>   4 in maven for transaction manager but in the maven i am configuring
>   the hibernate transaction manager of version 3, that's
>   incompatibility. I changed the spring configuration file like this.

```
<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
    <!-- <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate core doesn't require any dependency of annotations some make sure your pom does not have any dependency of hibernate-annotation or hibernate-common-annotation.

**My working pom is as follows.**

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MYSQL dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- If using JPA (2), add: -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

By remove hibernate-common-annotations I got different error
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.SessionFactoryImplementor

This is to with version difference between session factory and transaction manager

here is the link for the solution
[http://devjav.com/spring-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-engine-sessionfactoryimplementor/][1]

Solution from the link above:
Using right version Hibernate for transaction manager and Local session factory bean

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

```
 <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" name="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="configLocation">
           <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Please include the solution with your answer, since the link might not always be available.